# How can I set selected tab in EPiServer CMS edit view?

Tags: c#, .net, dojo, content-management-system, episerver

We have an EPiServer (forms) edit view with a number of tabs. The customer has requested that the tab which is #2 (called "alternative content"), should be automatically selected under certain conditions when the editors open the edit-page. We don't want to reorder the tabs. How can this be accomplished? We're running EPiServer 11.

**Update:**

I've tried to accomplish this using a Dojo-script. The result in EPiServer depends on how I set it up, which is kinda strange to me in this case. Here's the file

*Web\modules\CMSDefaultTabSelector\module.config*:

[image: module.config]

Here's how it's called in ModifyMetadata:

[image: Calling code in ModifyMetadata]

...and the script itself, CMSDefaultTabSelector.js, looks like this:

[image: CMSDefaultTabSelector.js]

The result, depending on whether you send in  EditLayoutContainer, Dialog, or skip it entirely (the way it *should* look), is as follows:

**Result with EditLayoutContainer**

[image: Result with EditLayoutContainer]

**Result with Dialog**

[image: Result with Dialog]

**The result as it should be**

[image: Result original]

If I try to skip this parameter, I get the error *"ctor is not a constructor"*. Other layout elements just render an empty tab, weirder errors, or you get other error messages. If I use `require([...])`, the function is called on every page reload, which is *not* what I want. I want it to only be called whenever the code from ModifyMetadata kicks in. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I honestly don't think there's any way of doing this without creating a custom Dojo widget which could, for example, subscribe to the `contentContextChanged` event to determine if a different tab should be selected.


If you're willing to change the sort order, you could conditionally show/hide tabs or change the sort order when specific conditions are met. This might prove helpful: https://gregwiechec.com/2018/03/hide-tabs-and-properties-in-edit-mode/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've already accomplished most of this, and I've almost landed the Dojo-part. I'm able to selectively load the widget in the ModifyMetaData function, and I preform a JS-click on the tab I want to select when the Dojo-DOM is loaded. At this point I was more curious whether there was a smarter way to do this, because it feels a bit like hopping through hoops and architecture just to perform a simple hello world.

Comment: @Ted: I've updated the question with new info and the Dojo-approach (which has its own quirks).

Comment: Did you try inheriting `LayoutContainer`? If so, how is that rendered? Otherwise I would refrain from changing `ClientLayoutClass` and instead simply hook up to suitable event(s). You can use `registry` to find the `dijit.layout.TabContainer` widgets in the UI to interact with the one for the edit tabs.

Comment: FYI, I'm quite new to this. I've tried "dijit/layout/TabContainer" (results in an empty tab), "dijit/layout/ContentPane" (tab with just the properties, no space, and no leading text), "epi/shell/layout/LayoutContainer" (results in a tab with the properties and correct spacing, but still no leading text for each property), and "epi/shell/layout/GroupContainer" (yields a tab with properties and leading text intact, but with the tab header text repeated a second time inside the tab). It's the closest we've gotten thus far.
Not sure how to use the registry to find the TabContainer, like you say.

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around for quite a while, I finally found the magic code. Since other people might also wonder how this is done, here's how it was solved in the end (using Dojo):

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"epi/shell/layout/SimpleContainer"
],

function (
    declare,
    SimpleContainer
)
{
    return declare([SimpleContainer], {
        //constructor: function () {},

        postCreate: function () { /* PostCreate fires too soon, and the tab strip is not completely rendered */ },

        startup: function () {
            // Use Jquery to select the tab we manually want to change to, and click it:
            var tabElement = $("div.dijitContentPane span.tabLabel:contains('Additional content')");
            if ($(tabElement).length) {
                $(tabElement).trigger("click");
            }
        }

    });
}
```

);

Comment: A widget hasn't necessarily been attached to the DOM when its `postCreate` event is fired, unlike `startup` which is fired once the widget has been rendered. See the _lifecycle_ on Dojo widgets: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetBase.html

Comment: Yep, I know. I added the comment for reference.